# is it dangerous to zip/unzip unknown uploaded files on server that may contain anything? even viruses?

Tags: php, apache, file, upload, compression

i am trying to implement a user system (php, apache) where the user can upload several files and download a zipped version of them. (or uploading a zipped file and download the uncompressed files).

**question:** is there any risk to zip/unzip those unknown files?
in other words, are unix/php zip/unzip operations treat files as text only or some execution can occur?

**This question is relevant to all compression methods, zip is just an example.**

**EDIT:** @Alex Brown AND @Parallelis wrote 2 risks so obviously it is not safe.
any one can post a short explanation on how to implement a safe compress/uncompress of unknown files?

Comment: The main danger would come from a zip file which encodes absolute paths.  Most unzip utilities have an option to force relative unpack, also you should sandbox or cheroot the unzip operation for safety.

Comment: There's a huge risk with ZIP file: you could encode a HUGE serie of 0's (or any other constant characters) into a small zip file, so when it is expanded, you may fill quickly your fle system!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As It seems reasonable to me. You cant do this because of some issues, what if those files are bootstrap scripts? (Refer comments of Alex and Parallelis for 2 more issues).

Solutions :

1. If you going to store the zip files as zip files after being uploaded, Doing so you will face additional issues since zips can contain lots of files that may or may not be appropriate. In that case you may want to get a list of the contents of the file to automatically include in your field so people downloading them will know if the file contents are valid. You could also integrate with something like [ClamAV](http://drupal.org/project/clamav) to scan all the files that are uploaded.

   Note: Google is doing same thing, they use their anti virus scanner programs (which offcourse are not available for public use).
2. Also you can place the file in a temporary directory first and then use zip_open on it in that location. Their you will be able to use OS level commands (which come with their own risks) to verify the integrity of the file without actually unzipping it. You can also refer this [tool](http://www.pkware.com/store/securezip/windows/command-line-interface) for same thing.

Comment: 1. the only user who will download those files is the one who uploaded them so i am not worried about the user, i am worried about the system. 2. file won't be executed but only compressed/uncompressed and downloaded. also in case of uncompress error i don't really care what the error is as long as nothing was executed on server nor overflowed HD space or RAM.

Comment: I have not spoke about users here, I have discussed some of ways to handle zip-files and contents of those zip system side using integration of scanner programs.

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential issues:

1. Zip bomb - this is generally not that much of an issue any more because most decompression tools / languages will prevent nested levels of decompression.
2. Relative paths: This in my mind is your biggest concern - the zip is decompressed, but it includes the file: `../../../../../../vendor/autoload.php` for example.. this then overwrites your autoload.php file and is executed whenever someone views your website. Game over.
3. A zillion inodes. A zip file may contain millions of 0 byte files, using up all your available inodes on the system. This would stop the hard disk being able to create new files on that partition. This could be medium-bad.

Answer (score 0):

You also should know that zip archives could contain symlinks. If user can read files after unzip, it is possible to read arbitrary files on your filesystem.

zip utility has --symlinks option for storing symlinks.